# Cannot use imported image with Unity's UI controls

Tags: unity

I know this question sounds banal but its a problem.

I received a project and opened it.

Now I try to edit it by adding my own images.

I do the import but the image does not show up when selecting images, for example, for a button:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzx34g51a1a3whm/unity.jpg?dl=0]

What is the correct folder in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your png is most likely not set to be imported as a sprite, and the property you want to use it in requires a sprite (background, checkmark and the others are by default sprites).

Click on your png to open up the import settings. The *Texture Type* dropdown menu is the interesting part here. Set it to *Sprite*, apply the changes and your sprite-ified png should now appear as selectable for your UI elements.

While at it, read about how it is possible to use raw textures for UI work (not sprites), and how this affects performance and should only be used in certain situations. Start here: http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html

Comment: that worked! many thanks! :-) The more precise I describe, the better the answers.